# Ball Selection without replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A box contains $2$ white balls, $3$ red balls and $4$ black balls.
Now I have to select $2$ balls one white and one red from the box without replacement. I'm confused between whether the probability will be $\frac{1}{6}$ or $\frac{1}{12}$. Can anyone please clear my confusion. Whether I have to consider the order or not.

Comment: Does order matter?

Comment: I'm confused with that part only.

Comment: 2/9 *3/8, how're you getting 1/6?

Comment: 2×3/ 9C2 = ⅙ in this way.

Answer (score 3):

$P(rw) = \frac{3}{9}\frac{2}{8} = \frac{1}{12}$

$P(wr) = \frac{2}{9}\frac{3}{8} = \frac{1}{12}$

So in both orders (which is what we care about: the end result is one white one red either way) we get $\frac{1}{6}$.

Note that this is the same as $$\frac{\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{0}}{\binom{9}{2}}$$ which is more the standard way of coming to this result, the above coming from the ordered view and then adding both orders.

Comment: Well going by this way we are considering RW and WR to be different, that is order is considered. Now try to solve picking up any two balls from the box with this method. Then check the probability would exceed 1.

Comment: @Sdas Well summing over all orders always gets us $1$.. And I count them separately and add them up because the end result is the same.

Comment: @Sdas, probability can never exceed $1$. You are probably doing wrong calculation. If you can, show how are you getting it more than $1$.

Comment: But selecting any two balls from the box should have a probability less than 1.

Comment: @Sdas It has. A multiplication of probabilities will be less than $1$.

Comment: Well considering the cases which will be (W,R),(R,W),(W,B),(B,W),(R,B),(B,R). Now calculate the individual probabilities. And then sum it.

Comment: @Sdas You also have $(R,R), (W,W),(B,B)$ as well. And they sum to $1$, really!

Comment: @Sdas they're all fractions with denominator $72$. $WR$ and $RW$ contribute $6$ each, $RB$ and $BR$ add $12$ each, $WB$ and $BW$ each bring $8$, while the equal pairs bring $2$, $6$ and $12$, and $12+24 + 16 + 2 + 6 + 12  =72$

Comment: @sdas - Please see details I have added in my answer. I hope it clarifies probability adding to 1.

Answer (score 0):

**It does not matter. If you draw one at a time,**

Sequence ${W R} = \dfrac{2C1}{9C1}.\dfrac{3C1}{8C1} = \dfrac {1}{12}$

Sequence ${R W} = \dfrac{3C1}{9C1}.\dfrac{2C1}{8C1} = \dfrac {1}{12}$

So it adds to $\dfrac{1}{6}$ .....(1)

**To clarify your confusion on probability adding to 1:**

Sequence ${W B} = \dfrac{2C1}{9C1}.\dfrac{4C1}{8C1} = \dfrac {1}{9}$

Sequence ${B W} = \dfrac{4C1}{9C1}.\dfrac{2C1}{8C1} = \dfrac {1}{9}$

So it adds to $\dfrac{2}{9}$ .....(2).

Sequence ${R B} = \dfrac{3C1}{9C1}.\dfrac{4C1}{8C1} = \dfrac {1}{6}$

Sequence ${B R} = \dfrac{4C1}{9C1}.\dfrac{3C1}{8C1} = \dfrac {1}{6}$

So it adds to $\dfrac{1}{3}$ .....(3)

Then you have events where both ball colors are the same -

Sequence ${W W} = \dfrac{2C1}{9C1}.\dfrac{1C1}{8C1} = \dfrac {1}{36}$ .....(4)

Sequence ${R R} = \dfrac{3C1}{9C1}.\dfrac{2C1}{8C1} = \dfrac {1}{12}$ .....(5)

Sequence ${B B} = \dfrac{4C1}{9C1}.\dfrac{3C1}{8C1} = \dfrac {1}{6}$ .....(6)

**Add (1) to (6), that will add up to 1.**

Comment: Well going by this way we are considering RW and WR to be different, that is order is considered. Now try to solve picking up any two balls from the box with this method. Then check the probability would exceed 1.

Comment: No it would not exceed 1. Can you please elaborate what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I was doing a silly calculation mistake. My bad.

Comment: Understood. That is what I thought.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle P(1W \& 1R)=P(WR)+P(RW)=\frac{2}{9}\cdot \frac{3}{8}+\frac{3}9\cdot\frac{2}8=\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{12}=\frac{2}{12}=\frac{1}{6}$